# How to access named attribute on elements with another given attribute value

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to come up with an XPath to the following XML:

```
<A>
   <Target attr1="foo" attr2="bar"/>
   <B>
      <Target attr1="forest" attr2="gump"/>
      <C>
          <Target attr1="foo" attr2="aDifferentKindOfBar"/>    
      </C>
      <C/>
   </B>
</A>
```

It should give me the value of attribute named "attr2" for all elements Target that have an attribute "attr1" with value "foo".

So in my example I would like to get "bar" and "aDifferentKindOfBar" but not "gump".

I came as far as:

```
//Target[@attr1='foo']
```

But I can't figure out how to get the navigation to the attribute "attr2".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the next step to the path:

```
//Target[@attr1='foo']/@attr2
```